# Python Pandas Dataframe - Drop group based on Groupby and filter condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has the following columns. I want to group the data by the order number and then drop all the groups that do not contain one specific item.

| order_id | product_id | purchase_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 23546.0. | 2020-01-10. |
| 1234. | 32423.0 | 2020-01-10. |
| 5678. | 43244.0. | 2020-02-10. |

when I use the line below if doesn't drop order_id 5678

```
df6 = df2.groupby(by='order_id').filter(lambda df2: df2['product_id'] == 23546.0)
```

I get the error:
'DataFrame' object is not callable

Comment: Can you post full traceback?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df.loc[df['product_id'].eq('23546.0.').groupby(df['order_id']).transform('any')]

   order_id product_id purchase_date
0    1234.0   23546.0.   2020-01-10.
1    1234.0    32423.0   2020-01-10.
```

if product_id is float

```
df.loc[df['product_id'].eq(23546.0).groupby(df['order_id']).transform('any')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
df_out = df.groupby(by="order_id").filter(lambda x: 23546.0 in x["product_id"].values)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   order_id  product_id purchase_date
0    1234.0     23546.0    2020-01-10
1    1234.0     32423.0    2020-01-10
```